# Confusing *CGLIB class names when Dynamic Proxy should be used in Spring Boot/MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cglib

As far as I know whenever I use interfaces for my beans, JDK Dynamic Proxies should be used instead of CGLIB. To be on teh safe side, I make sure I don't even have CGLIB in the classpath of my Spring Boot app.
However, when my controller implements an interface I see this in the stacktrace(never mind the stacktrace rootcause, it was a validation error):

```
    at com.yuranos.documented.api.controllers.BookingControllerImpl.convertToDto(BookingControllerImpl.java:57)
    at com.yuranos.documented.api.controllers.BookingControllerImpl.getBookingById(BookingControllerImpl.java:29)
    at com.yuranos.documented.api.controllers.BookingControllerImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$890fcd8a.invoke(<generated>)
```

What is even more confusing is that when I remove the interface, this strangely named proxy disappears:

```
    at com.yuranos.documented.api.controllers.BookingControllerImpl.convertToDto(BookingControllerImpl.java:60)
    at com.yuranos.documented.api.controllers.BookingControllerImpl.getBookingById(BookingControllerImpl.java:32)
```

Comment: Spring boot by default uses class based proxies and as of Spring 4 (or even 3.2) Spring ships with its own internally repacked version of cglib. So removing the dependency won't even work as Spring ships with its own.